# Как лучше реализовать режим разработки?

Tags: php, архитектура

Есть проект написанный на PHP на паттерне MVC. Всё самописное. И вот проект растёт и необходимо вносить серьёзные правки. А потом их ещё протестировать. И встал вопрос, как лучше сделать так, чтобы пока ты заливаешь файлы тестируешь работу пользователи видели страницу, говорящую о том что, например, Идёт обновление портала. Сегодня я придумал только такое решение: в файле index.php ввёл константу и везде проверяю её.

Comment: Сделайте поддомен для тестирования. И вам проще, и в работе сайта перерывов не будет.

Comment: Пользователи вообще не должны что-то там знать о том что вы что-то тестируете и проверяете. Как уже сказано выше - делается аналогичный боевому тестовый сервер, на котором все тестируется.

Comment: Делаешь обновление на копии проекта в домене например `beta.domain.com`, после всех обновлений просто меняешь их местами с основным.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Есть второй домен. аналогичный первому. Проблема возникает при тестировании. Например: вносятся новые методы или условия отправки писем, то чтобы не уходило реальным клиентам необходимо комметить части кода. Потом это забывается вроде всё работает. и заливается на боевой. И пошли жалобы. Потом ты вспомнил, исправил. А время и нервы потрачены в пустую.

Comment: @Эникейщик Второй пример: В процессе перезаписи файлов, кто-то может что-то передавать в БД. Перезаписью я это сломаю. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы очень просто все пользователи видели уведомление, что ведутся работы. Обновил всё открыл доступ.

Comment: @doox911 смотри в сторону Git

Comment: @dev_null Я знаю что такое Git. Гит даст быстрый откат, если что не так. А мне необходима концепция для уведомления пользователей об обновлении портала. Или я устарел, и сейчас это вообще не модно? Просто сервиса https://beget.com/ru обновление системы именно через уведомление.

Comment: Я думаю, что такие крупные порталы, как Beget, расположены не на одном сервере, поэтому обновляться приходится с извращениями

Comment: Ну если Вам так все принципиально, то добавите на главной странице редирект по условию